# Vertically align using margin-top

Tags: javascript, alignment, center

I'm trying to vertically centre my division.

I need something that tells the 'margin-top' to -50% of the division.

You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/N5gsW/

I know I'm doing something wrong :(

Thanks

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="content">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent iaculis quam non massa venenatis malesuada. Ut mollis, nibh id placerat euismod, magna lectus sodales lacus, nec ultrices.
</div>
```

CSS

```
body{
margin: 0 0 0 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
#content{
width: 100px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -50px;
top: 50%; 
position: fixed;
background: #0C6;
}
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#content').each(function() {
    var parentHeight = $(this).parent().height();
    var thisHeight = $(this).height();
    var topmargin = (parentHeight - thisHeight) / 2;
    $(this).css("margin-top", topmargin);
});
})
```

Comment: Edited, didn't know, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The margin top needs to be `-50px`, worked out like so

`margin-top = -(height / 2)px`

Comment: nope, like this http://jsfiddle.net/N5gsW/6/ Notice the minus sign. You also needed to load in jquery for the fiddle to work.

Comment: Works on JSFiddle fine, but for some reason when I upload it online it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

In your JSFiddle u forget to add Jquery library!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#content').each(function() {
        var thisHeight = $(this).height();
        var topmargin = -(thisHeight) / 2;
        $(this).css("margin-top", topmargin);
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/N5gsW/7/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#content').each(function() {
        var topmargin = $(this).height() / 2;
        $(this).css("margin-top", -topmargin);
    });
})
```